# Why is this true? (standard a-priori estimate on linear parabolic PDE)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I read this:

> We see that
>   $$\frac{1}{2}\lVert u(T) \rVert^2_{L^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\lVert u(0) \rVert^2_{L^2} + \lVert f \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1})}\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(0,T;H^1_0)}$$
>   and since $T$ is arbitrary, we have
>   $$\lVert u \rVert^2_{L^\infty(0,T;L^2)} \leq \lVert u(0) \rVert^2_{L^2} + \lVert f \rVert^2_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1})}$$

How is that true? I see he used Young's inequality on the RHS but what happened to the other term of Young's inequality?

Comment: Can you give a reference to the source of this statement?

Comment: @5PM See http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/notes/nonlinev.pdf, page 66.